# ionic cordova keyboard hiding input

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

1. Overlaps my text input with ionic keyboard.

`cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"` ionic keyboard version

**Ionic info :** this my ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.15
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.8.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.0.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.1, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: >maybe i need to added adjustPan but it's not working.

**Anyone have any idea how to add adjustPan to ionic**

Answer (score 2):

Add this library

```
 ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard
 npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard@4
```

Use this below code.

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { }


this.keyboard.show();

this.keyboard.hide();
```

Comment: **Keyboard.show (for Android only)**
1)Show the keyboard
2)Call this method to show the keyboard.
`Keyboard.show();`

this is not useful to me

Comment: Did you fix that?

Answer (score 1):

For capacitor add this to

```
        "Keyboard": {
          "resize": "body",
          "style": "DARK",
          "resizeOnFullScreen": true
        }
      }
```

under capacitor.config.json

Your final config should look like this:

```
{
    "appId": "io.ionic.starter",
    "appName": "MyApp",
    "webDir": "www",
    "bundledWebRuntime": false,
    "plugins": {
        "Keyboard": {
          "resize": "body",
          "style": "DARK",
          "resizeOnFullScreen": true
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this for using "capacitor" right ?

Comment: Yes for Capacitor